# Can't figure out why my switch isn't working. Seems to not be recognizing the cin input

Tags: c++

I'm confused as to why my switch won't work, even though I have it set to an integer value. I'm going to be adding more to the program later; just right now trying to initiate options from the menu using a switch.

My switch format looks correct and other examples I've looked at have a very similar look. Though it might be because `num` could be seen as a string, but I have it set to an integer and have only tried inputting a `1` to initiate case `1`. `num` could be entered in as any positive integer and have three cases for the numbers `1`, `2`, and `3`, each having their their own outputs and a default for any numbers other than those three.

Could someone please help me understand why the switch isn't working?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const double PI = 3.14159;

int main ()
{
  int num;
  double a,b,c;
  double radius, width, length, base, height;

  cout << "Shape menu" << endl; // gives user a menu and 3 options
  cout << "1. Circle" << endl;
  cout << "2. Rectangle" << endl;
  cout << "3. Triangle" << endl;
  cout << "Choose a shape (1, 2, or 3)" << endl;
  cin >> num; // don't get why the switch isn't reading this value

  /* ignore this its for later i just wanted to have the formula written down
  a = PI * pow(radius,2);
  b = width * length;
  c = (base * height) / 2;
  */


  switch (num){

  case1:
      cout << "What is the radius?" << endl;

      break;

  case2:
      cout << "Enter width" << endl;
      cout << "Enter length" << endl;

      break;

  case3:
      cout << "Enter base" << endl;
      cout << "Enter height" << endl;

      break;
  }

return 0;
}

  // compiles fine just doesn't run correctly
```

Comment: Forgot a couple of spaces maybe?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A space is required between the word `case` and the actual value for each of the cases. So `case1` should actually be `case 1`. So for your code, this:

```
  case1:
/*...*/
  case2:
/*...*/
  case3:
/*...*/
```

Should be changed to this:

```
  case 1:
/*...*/
  case 2:
/*...*/
  case 3:
/*...*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this really compile? You're missing a space, it should be

```
case 1:
```

Comment: Without the space, `case1:` becomes a label - the target for a `goto` statement. That's why it compiles.